# How do I define a text area using sed and printf in tcl

Tags: tcl

Hi im try to add a definded text area `%-74s` using sed and printf in a tcl script i have but im not sure how to add the printf info to the line of code i have

`puts $f "sed -i "s/XXXTLEXXX/\$1/\" /$file";`

any help would be greatly appreciated
ive tried a few combinations but all error

Comment: I fail to see what you are trying to achieve. You want to call `sed` from the Tcl script, then you should be using [`exec`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm).

Comment: I would like to incorporate the printf function %-74s in my sed line to define the white spacing between a border

Comment: What's Tcl's role in that play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a need to peint a string with limited substitutions in it, yet that string contains `$`, `"` and `\` characters in it. Those special characters mean that using a normal double-quoted word in Tcl is very awkward; you could use lots of backslashes to quote the TCL metacharacters, but that's horrible when most of the string is in another language (shell/sed in your case). Here is a better option with `string map` and a brace-quoted word (which is free of substitutions):

```
set str {sed -i "s/XXXTLEXXX/$1/" /%FILE%}
puts $f [string map [list "%FILE%" $file] $str]
```

Note that you can do multiple substitutions in one `string map`, and that it does each substitution wherever it can. You can use a multi-line literal too. (`%FILE%` was chosen to be a literal that didn't otherwise occur in the string. Pick your own as you need them, but putting the name in helps with readability.)

Comment: just to make sure im right do i add the %-74s part where the %FILE% goes so it becomes set str {sed -i "s/XXXTLEXXX/$1/" /%-74s%} ?